# Draw centered align line on top of a minipage

Tags: minipage

I want to draw a colored line with any line width at the top of a `minipage`. The result I am aiming for is this:
[image]

My minimal working example is as following

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{color}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newenvironment{myenv}{
    
    \textcolor{cyan}{Some title}
    
    \vspace{2pt}
    
    \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
    \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][t]{10cm}
    
    \colorbox{cyan}{\makebox[10cm][sep=0, wd=0.25cm, ht=0.7cm, center]{\strut}}
            }{
    \end{minipage}\end{lrbox}\colorbox{yellow}{\usebox{\mybox}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
Some text
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

Which compiles to the following
[image]

As you can see, the blue line gets somewhat shifted. I've tried to Ti*k*Z the line, I get the same problem of a minimal with shift by using Ti*k*Z.

Any suggestions to how I can get my line centered according to the `minipage` and stuck to the top of the `minipage`?

Comment: See, if `tcolorbox` can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Zarko. I'll check it out!

Comment: @matkapluku You might want to take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624743/unaccounted-space-at-left-of-tikzpicture/624761#624761 -- I looked at this using Ti*k*Z and found something interesting, along with some useful code.

Answer (score 1):

I propose this solution with a simple `\rule` command:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{color}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newenvironment{myenv}{

\textcolor{cyan}{Some title} \vspace{2pt}

\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\begin{minipage}[c][5cm][t]{10cm}%
{\hskip-\fboxsep\color{cyan}\smash{\rule[-0.95ex]{\dimexpr10cm + 2\fboxsep}{0.25cm}}\vskip 1ex}}
{%
\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}\colorbox{yellow}{\usebox{\mybox}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
Some text
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

[image]