# Unaccounted space at left of tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

In thinking about a solution for another question ([Draw centered align line on top of a minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569772/draw-centered-align-line-on-top-of-a-minipage), not submitted), I ran across an oddity. There seems to be what looks like a spurious space at the *left* of a `tikzpicture`, about 2pt. Not a huge problem, and easily worked around, but curious. I have added `%` to every line end in an attempt to make sure that no space is being inadvertently added.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenvii}{m}{%
    \parindent0pt%
    \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
        \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][t]{10cm}% both minipage and varwidth work here
        \vspace*{3pt}%
}{%
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \noindent
    %\kern-2pt%% --->>> fixes the problem, but why necessary?!?!?
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \node[draw=cyan,fill=yellow](R){\usebox{\mybox}};
        \draw[line width=1ex,cyan] (R.north west) -- (R.north east);
        \node[inner xsep=0pt,cyan,above=2pt of R.north west,anchor=south west] {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent Some text outside Ti\emph{k}Z.

\begin{myenvii}{Some title}%
Some text This is some more to see just what happens here and what happens if there is a lit of text to see.
\end{myenvii}

\noindent$\uparrow$ note the gap here, about 2pt.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The culprit is `\draw[line width=1ex,cyan] (R.north west) -- (R.north east);`. Comment it out and everything aligns just fine.

Comment: Interesting. It works, but the `\draw` is an essential part of the figure. Is this a flaw or a feature? Curious that I've never run across that before.

Comment: Ah. You have jogged my memory. Change `\draw[line width=1ex,cyan]` to `\draw[line width=0ex,cyan]` and  the problem goes away as well.

Comment: I think it is the normal behaviour of Ti*k*Z to extend the bounding box to half the line width beyond the ends of the line. (See the comments to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/593487/47927 , I was not able to find another source that quickly.)

Comment: After reflection, it make sense that horizontal lines are a special case; vertical lines would certainly have to alter the horizontal dimensions of the bounding box. There. I learned something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is:

```
\draw[line width=1ex,cyan] (R.north west) -- (R.north east);
```

To see the problem, try:

```
\draw[line width=1ex,cyan,line cap=rect] (R.north west) -- (R.north east);
```

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenvii}{m}{%
  \parindent0pt%
  \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
    \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][t]{10cm}% both minipage and varwidth work here
      \vspace*{3pt}%
    }{%
    \end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \noindent%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0pt]%
    \node[draw=cyan,fill=yellow](R){\usebox{\mybox}};
    \fill[fill=cyan] (R.north west) rectangle ([yshift=1ex]R.north east);
    \node[inner xsep=0pt,cyan,above=1ex of R.north west,anchor=south west] {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent Some text outside Ti\emph{k}Z.

\begin{myenvii}{Some title}%
Some text This is some more to see just what happens here and what happens if there is a lit of text to see.
\end{myenvii}
\end{document}

\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=0pt]%
    \node[draw=cyan,fill=yellow](R){%
      toto% \usebox{\mybox}%
    };
    \fill[fill=cyan] (R.north west) rectangle ([yshift=1ex]R.north east);
    \node[inner xsep=0pt,draw,cyan,above=2pt of R.north west,anchor=south west] {Title};
    \draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah. Avoid the issue with `\draw` altogether. Neat.

Comment: A rule is, after all, a special case of a filled rectangle -- as your code demonstrates.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider to use `tcolorbox` for your new environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % in real document remove option "showframe" 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{%
enhanced,
title=#1,
fonttitle=\Large\bfseries,
coltitle=cyan,
attach boxed title to top left,
boxed title style={colframe=white,
                   colback=white,
                   },
%
before=\par\medskip\noindent,
    colframe=cyan,  colback=yellow!30,
    boxrule=1pt,    toprule=6pt,
    boxsep=3pt,
    arc=0mm,
    left=3pt,right=0mm,top=3pt,bottom=3pt,
%after=\noindent,   % <--- if you wish no indented text after box
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{mybox}{Some title}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}
\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `use as bounding box`:

- Draw everything that should account for the final bounding box. In OP's example the two nodes.
- Use `\path[use as bounding box] ...;` to specify a fixed bounding box.
- Add rest paths that won't affect the bounding box any more. Here is the cyan rule.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenvii}{m}{%
    \parindent0pt%
    \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
        \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][t]{10cm}% both minipage and varwidth work here
        \vspace*{3pt}%
}{%
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \noindent
    %\kern-2pt%% --->>> fixes the problem, but why necessary?!?!?
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
        \node[draw=cyan,fill=yellow](R){\usebox{\mybox}};
        \node[inner xsep=0pt,cyan,above=2pt of R.north west,anchor=south west]  (title) {#1};
        \path[use as bounding box] (title.north west) rectangle (R.south east);
        \draw[line width=1ex, cyan] (R.north west) -- (R.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent Some text outside Ti\emph{k}Z.

\begin{myenvii}{Some title}%
Some text This is some more to see just what happens here and what happens if there is a lit of text to see.
\end{myenvii}

\noindent$\uparrow$ note the gap disappears.

\end{document}
```

[image]